# Image ID undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, firefox

The following function to change image source on mouse hover/mouseout works in Chrome:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#img_home').mouseover(function() {
                img_home.src = 'img/btn/act/home2.gif';
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                img_home.src = 'img/btn/pas/home.gif';
            });
```

In Firefox the console displays 'img_home' not defined.

Here's the markup:

```
<a href="Default.aspx">
    <img alt="home" src="img/btn/pas/home.gif" 
     id="img_home" style="border: none" />
</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this`, it will refer back to relevant element:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img_home').mouseenter(function() {
       this.src = 'img/btn/act/home2.gif';
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
       this.src = 'img/btn/pas/home.gif';
 });
```

Comment: And for those, who like me, wondered about the mouseenter and leave: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element, not its id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img_home').mouseover(function() {
        this.src = 'img/btn/act/home2.gif';
    }).mouseout(function() {
       this.src = 'img/btn/pas/home.gif';
    });
});
```

Comment: You could use its id … but not as a variable name before you've assigned anything to it. `this` is the sensible approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want:

```
$('#img_home').src = ...
```

Unless you've defined the img_home variable before the code snippet you added, there is no known variable with a name of img_home.